# Default AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage to True Globally in SSIS

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, when connecting to certain non-SQL Server databases via the OLE DB provider you may encounter this error:

> Cannot retrieve the column code page info from the OLE DB provider.  If the component supports the "DefaultCodePage" property, the code page from that property will be used.  Change the value of the property if the current string code page values are incorrect.  If the component does not support the property, the code page from the component's locale ID will be used.

This error can generally be suppressed by setting the `AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage` property to `True` on the Source component.

My question is, can the `AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage` property be set so the default is `True`?  It's a bit annoying to always have to set this for each source.

Assuming it IS possible, would there be instances where this would actually be bad?  I haven't been able to determine if there would ever be a case that this would cause an issue.  I'm mostly dealing with Informix (en_us.819 locale) and MS SQL Server (Latin1 collation), if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to change the default setting from 'false' to 'true':

- [AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage: Can I change the default to True?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53075dc2-1b84-447e-89f9-6650ebb54d0c/alwaysusedefaultcodepage-can-i-change-the-default-to-true?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

If, for example, your source data is in Japanese and your AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage =True then it seems that you will likely import Japanese characters into your ETL process. Though, I haven't tested this.

- [OLE DB Custom Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-custom-properties)

Comment: Right, I'll assume I've missed something here. How does this not answer the questions?

Comment: Actually, it is my fault. I was reviewing earlier and my internet was a bit unstable, accidentally clicked the wrong button. Disregard my comment.